# Will it be useful to use a blockchain when number of blocks are less?

Tags: blockchain

I recently started learning about blockchain. I have been asked to make a project on blockchain where I have to maintain new versions of trades made in a bank. Old versions should not be tampered with. So i was thinking of using blockchain for this, but I realised that number of blocks formed for each trade would be very less(say around 50). So will it be safer to use blockchain in this case as number of blocks will be less. Also can anyone tell me how I should add new blocks in the blockchain in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it the wrong way around. 50 blocks per trade is ridiculous. 50 trades per block would be logical. But it's up to you to decide how big a block is. 500 trades is also a possibility.

That said, a blockchain for a bank does not make sense. Blockchains are a form of distributed databases; within a single bank it's pointless. A bank trusts itself.

Comment: Ok I understand it but i am asking about building a private blockchain for the bank. Also can you tell me another way to add blocks in blockchain without using the whole rewarding sytem(Mining).

Comment: Also can you please answer my question will the blockchain be still secure if there are only few blocks in a blockchain?